# Why do I only see the 'default' DB when linking an Oracle server in SQL Server 2008 Mgmt Studio?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, oracle

When I add an Oracle server as a Linked Server in SQL Server 2008 Management Studio, I can only see a database named 'default', and none of the other DB's on the server.  Using *Microsoft OLD DB Provider for Oracle* or *Oracle Provider for OLE DB*--same result.

I map my local login to the remote user for the Oracle server, so it should not be a permissions issue.

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what permissions are granted to the schema you're connecting to on the Oracle side. Have you applied latest patches to your Management Studio client?

Comment: I don't think it's a permissions issue...  if I log into an Oracle DMBS tool I can see all the DB's I'm supposed to.  Using the same credentials with the server linking, I only see the one default db.  I believe my Mgmt Studio is up to speed--this seems to be a provider or provider config issue, don't you think?

Answer (score 1):

This may sound like a dumb follow-up question, but is this a 64-bit instance of SQL Server that you've created the linked server for Oracle on?

Comment: Not dumb at all, Tim--thank you for your time in weighing in.  The answer is no, I'm dealing with all 32-bit versions.

For now, the RDBMS integration I need is working via some OpenQuery queries (4-part name queries don't work well against non-SQL-Server RDBMS), so it's not a huge problem.  The SQL-Server-to-Oracle linking is working, just not looking the way I would expect.